# How to call a part of a function not the whole function in somewhere?

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, if-statement, call

I am trying to call a condition which is defined inside of a function in somewhere else but I don't know if it is possible.
this function is a member of a class:

```
  void CMainDlg::OnTcnSelchangeTab1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    int ii=M_TabCtrl1.GetCurSel();  

if(ii==0)
        {
         GetDlgItem....
         GetDlgItem....
        }
else if(ii==1)
   {
    ///GetDlgItem....
   ///GetDlgItem....
   }
else
  {
  ////
  }
  }
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

I am trying to call and execute the following loop directly somewhere else but I don't know how.

```
if(ii==0)
    {
GetDlgItem....
GetDlgItem....
}
```

Comment: Put it in its own function and call that from both places. (It's not a loop, though.)

Comment: Please put your code in a function. then call that function from both the places and bingo your problem is solved :) . Also as molddnilo said, its a condition not a loop. Also you might need to pass a argument to the function.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call a piece of code from somewhere else, you need to make it a function. You can then call this new function twice: from the original code location, and where you want to use it again:

```
void your_function()
{
    // Your 'loop'
    // Note that 'if' is not a loop but a condition
    if(ii==0)
    {
        GetDlgItem....
        GetDlgItem....
    }
}

void CMainDlg::OnTcnSelchangeTab1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    ...
    your_function();
    ...
}

// Somewhere else, call it again:
void something_else()
{
    ...
    your_function();
    ...
}
```

Comment: `If you want to call a piece of code from somewhere else, you need to make it a function`. What about `goto`?

Comment: @Levi In general `goto` is bad. In some cases it can be useful but given the level of OP's question I'm 99% sure they need a function.

Comment: I am aware that `goto` is bad. I was just attempting to correct a mistake (`you need to make it a function`). I think better wording would be `should` rather than `need to`

Comment: @Levi : a goto is not bad enough to allow you to enter in the middle of a function from the outside of the function ...

Answer (score 2):

C++ has not the old Fortran notion of *entry point* that allowed to enter directly in the middle of a procedure. In C++, a function or a method has one single entry point : its beginning.

It is better to put a clean structure : if one piece of code can be called from different points, make it a function or a method and then call it from where you need to do.